# Objective C - iPhone/ handle subView events on ParentView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, event-handling

I'm having issues trying to handle the events from a Subview of my Parent View, right now I have a UIViewController that has a a subView another UIViewController, in this subView I have a paging scrollView, I want to fire a method on the parent view when I swipe the subView scroll View, do you have any suggestions on how can I develop this?, thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what your situation is, and what you want to happen. Could you please explain more clearly, and/or add relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the parent view a delegate of the subview.

Add this to the SubView.h:

```
// add
@protocol SubViewClassNameDelegate
@required
- (void)triggerMethodFromSubView:(NSString *)value;
@end
//

@interface SubViewClassName : UIView

// add
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SubViewClassNameDelegate> delegate
//

@end
```

Then in your parent view class, add this to ParentView.h:

```
@interface ParentViewClassName : UIView /* add -> */ <SubViewClassNameDelegate>
```

and this in ParentView.m right after the instantiation of your subview:

```
[mySubView setDelegate:self];
```

Finally, add your delegate trigger method somewhere in ParentView.m:

```
- (void)triggerMethodFromSubView:(NSString *)value {

// do stuff

}
```

Now, you can call `[self.delegate triggerMethodFromSubView:@"Hello World"]` anywhere in your subview class, and it will tell the parent view to call your delegated method.

If you need additional info, here's a helpful tutorial: http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002

Comment: Thanks for your help @jhoneiser, I review some examples and I found out this, that solves the issue but I'm not sure if it is the proper one:

- First on my subView I imported the parent view,then I did something like this:

ParentViewControllerClass *parentViewController= (ParentViewControllerClass *)self.parentViewController;
    [parentViewController parentMethod:parameter];

it works but I don't know if it's the best way to do it, also because on the parent I'm importing the subView class and on the subViewClass I'm importing the parent class, please, let me know what do you think about it

Comment: Your last comment is a valid concern (parent importing subView + subView importing parent).  If you were to try to access the subview in the parentview as well as access the parentview from the subview, one would fail.  The delegate pattern is designed to overcome this.